# ListView with Rounded Edges

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

What is the best way to implement the following ListView with the corner edge in Flutter?

Since I need overlapping on the rounded corner, is there a certain implementation using Stack and Positioned for this?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Assim, what have you tried so far? Yes, it is possible to do this with Stack and positioned, but that wouln't be a ListView. Do you need a scroll? Lazy loading?

Comment: Hello @GaboBrandX, I’m reading about Stack and Positioned as I haven’t practiced that. Yes would love to know how to do it and make it scrollable with lazy loading please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a way to do it without the use of Stack and Positioned.

I created a ListView using the ListView.builder() with each row being two container (parent and child). The bottom container (parent) takes the background of the next row's colour from the array (index+1). Then I add a container with a rounded edge taking it's colour based on its index. If it was the last row, the bottom container will be transparent. This will give the result as expected.

```
  List<Color> colours = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.amber,
    Colors.brown,
    Colors.deepPurple,
  ];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: colours.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           return Container( // This is the back container which will show next cell colour on the rounded edge
              color: index + 1 < colours.length
                  ? colours[index + 1] // get next row background as back container background
                  : Colors.transparent, // Otherwise keep it transparent to prevent out of bounds error
              child: Container(
                height: 180,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius:
                  const BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(85.0)),
                  color: colours[index],
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    index.toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
           );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use a stack and then calculate positions of each item.

```
List<Color> colorsList = [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.blue];


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: colorsList.reversed
            .map(
              (color) => Positioned(
                    top: colorsList.indexOf(color).toDouble() * 60,
                    child: ListItem(
                      color: color,
                      text: "Animation",
                      onTap: _goToAnimationPage,
                    ),
                  ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Code of the ListItem:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  height: 100,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Material(
    color: color,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0)),
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

And the result:

[image]

Comment: That is a very good implementation but the problem is it's for a fixed number of items in the list. Is there a way to have it for an unknown number of items. Say the data comes from an API and I want it to display a larger number of items dynamically.

Comment: Yes sure, you can do it dynamically too. Just calculate the heights and usa a map function.